# Ajax returning success but not updating database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my javascript and ajax code, it's returning success but the database is not updating, any ideas? Thanks. SOLVED

```
        function send_data()
        {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var keywords = $('#keywords').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var cat1 = $('#cat1').val();
        var cat2 = $('#cat2').val();
        var cat3 = $('#cat3').val();
        var id = $('#id').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "updateproductsgo.php?name=" + name + "&keywords=" + keywords + "&description=" + description + "&cat1=" + cat1 + "&cat2=" + cat2 + "&cat3" + cat3 + "&id=" + id,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
        alert('success');
        // use the result as you wish in your html here
        jQuery("#results").html(result);
        }});

        }
```

This is my code on updateproductsgo.php

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("xxx",$con);
$id=$_GET['id'];
$name=$_GET['name'];
$keywords=$_GET['keywords']; 
$description=$_GET['description']; 
$cat1=$_GET['cat1'];
$cat2=$_GET['cat2'];
$cat3=$_GET['cat3'];

$query = "UPDATE xxx SET name = '$name', keywords = '$keywords', description = '$description', cat1 = '$cat1', cat2 = '$cat2', cat3 = '$cat3' WHERE id = '$id'";
echo $query;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Updated the $query, didn't make a difference though.

Solved! There was an = missing off the url. Basic stuff!!

Comment: If something went wrong with the query the JavaScript won't know. You can however return errors in that die statement if something did go wrong. You could also try logging the mysql_error in a log file of some sorts. The code executes and the request to the PHP code is succesfull, that is why the success part in your code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your update query have missing comma

```
$query = "UPDATE products SET name = '$name', keywords = '$keywords', description = '$description', cat1 = '$cat1', cat2 = '$cat2', cat3 = '$cat3' WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: There was also an = missing on the url. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma and single quote in the query.

$query = "UPDATE products SET name = '$name', keywords = '$keywords',description = '$description', cat1 = '$cat1', cat2 = '$cat2', cat3 = '$cat3' WHERE id = '$id'";

Answer (score 0):

Print $query and check in phpmyadmin whether the query you printed is working or not. if not then check your query you missed comma at each place where you are setting a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what version of php you are using.

> As of php 5.5.x the original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and
>   will generate E_DEPRECATED errors.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

you might need to use mysqli.